# Cambiar el orden de las columnas - filas de una matriz R

Tags: r, matrices

Necesito añadir a esta matriz una fila de `0` (ceros) arriba y una columna de `0` a la izquierda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado hacerlo así...

```
R <- rbind(Hxx, 0)
R <- cbind(R, 0)
```

... pero me añade la fila y la columna al final. Cuando las he tenido al final, he probado con `R[,(1,8)]<- R[,(8,1)]`, pero no ha funcionado.

¿Cómo resolver esto?

Comment: Acá, es recomendable siempre mostrar lo que has intentado hacer para resolver tu duda.

Comment: ok, edito el mensaje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema se debe al orden de los argumentos.

Si tu matriz es `Hxx`, entonces `rbind(Hxx, 0)` pondrá primero en las filas a `Hxx` y luego 0, de esta forma la fila de 0s quedará al final. Por lo que tienes que hacer `rbind(0, Hxx)`. De la misma forma debe ser `R <- cbind(0, R)` para que la columna de ceros esté a la izquierda.

Recordar que tanto `rbind` y `cbind` son sensibles al orden de los argumentos!

Comment: Mil gracias @jbkunst ! Te debo una birra!